# Workaround for accessing non-static property in a static context for Validation C#

Tags: c#, validation, static

Let's say I have the class `Wallet`:

```
public class Wallet
{
       public double Min { get; set; }

       public double Max { get; set; }

       public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

And let's say that the data is read from a database.

The user is able to modify `Value` from the UI.

I want to validate it somehow, so my initial thought was:

```
[Range(Min, Max, ErrorMessage = "The value is outside of bounds.")]
public double Value { get; set; }
```

But an error is thrown: `Cannot access non-static property in a static context attribute.`

Is there a workaround or do I have to create a custom validation?

Context: WPF MVVM application, C#

Comment: There's a lot of missing information here.  In WPF, normally, the `[Range]` attribute is used in conjunction with an [`INotifyDataErrorInfo` implementation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx), but you haven't shown any of that code in your question, nor have you shown the code from the static context from which you are calling the validation or the code that reads the data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move that validation to the setter, and throw the exact validation exception that the attribute class throws if any validation erros occur.